# WINDOWS 10 Pro does not see Second XEON CPU

Tags: xeon

E5 2383 v3 CPU issues

I have dual E5-2620 v3 CPU's installed and working well. I recently purchased two used E5-2683 v3 CPU/s to increase my CORE count for 3D Architectural design. Upon installation of the 2683's the MB BIOS Posted both CPU's just fine. THe BIOS reported the presence of both Chips with TEMP and Voltage information. However, upon starting Windows 10 Pro, the "System" only reported a single CPU present. I ran CPU-Z, and HWINFO and both programs report same (one CPU). CPU-Z reported the core and thread count to be 12 and 24 when it should have been 14 /28 respectively. I tried swapping the CPU slots and the same reported.

My question:

1. Is there something in the BIOS and or Windows I can do to say "Reset" so that both report as they do with the 2620's or are my findings indicative of a faulty CPU(s)? When I replaced the 2620's all is well again so I am at a loss.

   I need your help. Please advise. I would be happy to call and discuss with someone that has more expertise than me. I need to make a decision to try something else or return the CPU's for refund.  MORE DETAILSI am running an ASUS Z10PE-D8 WS board. I did swap the CPU's in opposite slots one and two and received the same reports in both POST and BIOS. The CPU's appear to be powering up (although one is running hotter than the other) but BOOT UP is fine. It's INSIDE Windows 10 Pro things go south. Are you suggesting that I install only one CPU at a time and see what happens after boot up? Ok.

   What do you make of CPU-Z only showing 12 Cores and not 14 Cores (Spec for this CPU)? Also, Here is what the supplier suggested I try.

   We tested it on ASUS Z10PA-D8 WS..With bios 3202. (I am Running 3304, they also claim their CPU-Z show the same MB as mine yet say they can only use one cpu slot. sounds odd to me.

   Here are some tips,which make you confirm the processor works or not.

   1. Motherboard need be protected.They will protect itself and shut down auto when you install CPU with incorrect operation or other wrong action.
   2. CPU Fans works well or not? CPU is installed properly or not?
   3. Is the power enough for electricity supply?If not,it will shut down too.
   4. Are all power lines properly connected or not?
   5. If you test and run it in computer case or other cases,it will be more likely to lead to short-circuit.You can try to test it without case.

   Additional Instructions from Supplier.
   There have two situations you may encounter when receive the them: the system automatic shutdown or the item cannot be lightened. Therefore, we give you a brief introduction about how to use it correctly.

   1. Don't touch the metal surface of the CPU, in case of electrical shock and circuit.
   2. When install the CPU on the motherboard, you need to notice the CPU’s direction of the needle, don't put in the opposite direction.(There are four corners on the surface of CPU, one of the angle has a triangle symbol---the same as CPU seat of the motherboard .)
   3. The installation process must be smooth and flat, and confirm the CPU with the CPU seat can connect smoothly.
   4. Press down the CPU with your hand, and fix the CPU well into the CPU seat.
   5. When install the CPU fans, you need to ensure the fans strength evenly with every four corners.
2. When you encounter the CPU runs Automatic Power Off and the time gets shorter and shorter, there is no doubt that something wrong with your CPU fan’s cooling equipment, for example,

   1. CPU do not coating thermal paste.
   2. CPU radiator power cord is unconnected or connection error.(Haven’t connected with the motherboard logo likes CPU FAN1 or CPU FAN2.)
   3. CPU fans was broken , they do not run or low rotating speed.
   4. If you have more platform(PC), we suggest you test the CPU directly on another test platform.
3. You have installed properly, but the CPU still unable to lighten. Please pay more attention, it must be properly installed but unable to lighten. In this situation, we can provide you solution as following:

   1. Remove the CPU first, and use eraser to wipe the metal surface, and you would know whether it has circuit or not.
   2. Try to insert and withdraw the memory. Memory kit will occur poor connection , you may need to discharge or insert and pluck the memory to solve this problem.
   3. Cleared out COMS(All the motherboard has a battery, this is motherboard’s COMS),there has a jumper wire on the edge of COMS. You can try to use the jump line to clear out the COMS and discharge the motherboard;
   4. Reinsert and pluck the electric source to supply power and connect pin for motherboard, such as 24P or 28P socket, you can withdraw and install it again, and CPU power supply socket (4P or 8P interface) can also play an important role in the discharge.
   5. Try again to install the CPU properly.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us the exact S-Spec of the two CPUs? Alternatively, can we get the full model name and stepping? Windows absolutely requires the two CPUs to be identical.

Answer (score 0):

In Msconfig sometimes setting these incorrectly will cause CPU not to work in Windows

[image]

Comment: So, how should we set the settings to make sure it works? And you may want to include *which* setting is important, because there are several options there.